How to remember the ring on the cylinder
I am using a cylinder to perform Boolean cuts on a cube
After the cutting is completed, I want to choose the rings on the original cylinder，like the picture show
Can selection be made through certain APIs or shortcut keys instead of manual selection


The selection state is copied from the target object when the boolean modifier is applied.

Yeah +1 to @unwave if you have those edges selected on the cylinder before applying the modifier they will be selected on the applied object.

@unwaveu yeah it works, But I still need to manually select. Is there a way to automatically select it

How is Blender supposed to know what you want to select? Automatically select all horizontal loops?

@unwave yeah,that's what i want to select

Try loop selecting on the edge, Alt+Click.
